# How to execute a dynamic "top" command on a remote server with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have to execute a "top" command on a remote server with Ansible Playbook.
But when I run the playbook, the transfer dont't successful 
Playbook:

```
---
 - name: CPU load
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

 - name: CPU load
    command: top
    register: cpu_result

 - debug:
     var: cpu_result.changed
```

P.S. "mpstat" command works right (with cpu.result.stdout_lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`top` by default runs in interactive mode and periodically updates the values displayed in terminal. You cannot get this functionality using Ansible, if this is what you meant by "dynamic".

Instead you can run it:

- in batch mode (`top -b -n 1`) in GNU version of `top`, or
- in logging mode (`top -l 1`) on other Unix flavours.